# Keras deep learning model returning inconsistent results when rerun with exact same hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running a deep learning model which outputs a sigmoid function between 0 and 1. The validation curves are not very good and not very consistent. However, what’s worse is that the model is very inconsistent. If I run the same model twice with the exact same code, i get completely different results.

If i run it with epochs 30, and see that at epochs 25 the values are great.
Come to run it with epochs 25, i get completely different results.
Run it again at epochs 30, completely new results.

I am rerunning in 2 cases (1) rerun all model (2) rerun only the DL code, keeping test train split the same.

Both are yielding completely different results.

How can i know if there might be an issue with my input data? Probably with the standardization?

Below is the code for the DL part.

Also including some of the learning curves at different iterations.

```
Model = Sequential()
Model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = 91, activation = ‘relu’))
Model.add(Dense(4, activation = ‘relu’))
Model.add(Dense(1, activation = ‘sigmoid’))

Model.compile(loss=‘Binary_crossentropy’, optimizer=‘adam’,metrics=[‘accuracy’])
History = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Current answers are good but it also depends on your traning vs validation set split of data, if your datasets are small the impact of a value being in or out of the the training dataset is usually greater, so if the split is random it might also have an impact

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the global `seed` as follows:

```py
seed = 1234
tf.random.set_seed(
    seed
)
```

This worked for me in Pytorch i never tried it in Tensorflow but you can try it.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Crispen's answer is correct, but just as a heads up, the reason that the model is so inconsistent based on a random seed is because it isn't very large. With larger models, random seeds have less of an effect on the training since more trainable variables in a model allow for multiple ways for the loss to reach a reasonable minima. I would suggest increasing the number of units of the dense layers.

Example:

```
Model = Sequential()
Model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=91, activation=‘relu’))
Model.add(Dense(16, activation=‘relu’))
Model.add(Dense(1, activation=‘sigmoid’))
```